# KDE Plasma, virtual keyboard on login

Tags: kde, login-screen, sddm

I see complaints online going back as far as 2009 about a large virtual keyboard that appears *and covers* the login prompt upon system boot.

1. Boot.
2. Login screen quickly disappears and is replaced by a virtual keyboard.

I see several sources saying to add to `/etc/sddm.conf`:

```
InputMethod=
```

But this did *not* get rid of the virtual keyboard for me (but it did seem to bung up window title bars and break my VPN). So I've undone that change and it's back to normal now.

[One post](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/general/kde-neon/67010-keyboard-displayed-on-login-screen?p=585093#post585093) suggested to uninstall qt5-virtualkeyboard but [a follow-up](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=143332#p385530) noted that this removed other essential packages and broke the system, requiring OS reinstallation. So I *ahem* hesitate to do that.

So... what is the least risky way to get rid of that virtual keyboard?

EDIT: Per comment (and my fault for omitting)...

```
$ uname -a
Linux dlm-21cx 5.15.0-57-lowlatency #63-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 29 10:18:23 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu Studio 22.04, KDE Plasma 5.24.7, KDE Frameworks 5.92.0, Qt 5.15.3.

```
$ apt-cache policy sddm
sddm:
  Installed: 0.19.0-2ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 0.19.0-2ubuntu2.2
```

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I edited the question to include some of those.

Answer (score 0):

You must add InputMethod under the General section in /etc/sddm.conf:

```
[General]
InputMethod=
```

This can be seen in the example config output from

```
sddm --example-config
```